# VB Function giving errors- Syntax error missing operator in query expression '[!D]'=123 AND [POID] = & MfrOrderID & (3075) –

Tags: ms-access

Im trying to get the values of raw material required to fulfill a production order, product recipe is stored in another table with required quantities im using this simple function to get the values from query

```vb
Function GetRMWt(ProductID) As Long
    GetRMWt = DLookupNumberWrapper("[RM Req]", "RMCalc", "[ID]=" & ProductID & " AND [POID] = & MfrOrderID &")
End Function
```

and calling this function to get the values

```vb
Private Sub Product_ID_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsNull(Me![Product ID]) Then
        Me![Quantity] = GetRMWt(Me![Product ID])
        Me.Quantity.Locked = False
        Me![Unit Price] = GetListPrice(Me![Product ID])
        Me![Discount] = 0
        Me![Status ID] = None_OrderItemStatus
    Else
        eh.TryToRunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the query that fetches the required data

```sql
SELECT Products.ID
    ,ProductReceipe.PID
    ,ProductReceipe.[Product ID]
    ,[Mfr Order Details].Quantity AS [Item Qty]
    ,ProductReceipe.Quantity AS [RM Qty]
    ,([Item Qty] * [RM Qty] / 1000) AS [RM Req]
    ,[Mfr Order Details].[Mfr Order ID] AS POID
    ,IGROrders.[IGR Order ID]
FROM ProductReceipe
    ,[Mfr Order Details]
    ,[Mfr Orders]
    ,IGROrders
    ,Products
WHERE ProductReceipe.PID ) = [Mfr Order Details].[Product ID]
    AND [Mfr Orders].[Mfr Order ID] = [Mfr Order Details].[Mfr Order ID]
    AND [Mfr Orders].[Mfr Order ID] = [IGROrders].[Mfr Order ID]
    AND Products.ID = ProductReceipe.[Product ID]
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask],! By [formating sql code](http://poorsql.com/) many errors are revealed!

Comment: Syntax error missing operator in query expression '[!D]'=123 AND [POID] = & MfrOrderID & (3075)

Comment: And did you check your sql code, as I suggested (there is an error)? After formating it's easier to read. Or put the sql code in a saved query and try to run it!

Comment: Not question title!, right after the function that raises the error! You found error in sql? Now show code of `DLookupNumberWrapper`. Error is caused by wrong usage of its parameters! Search for "vba concat strings and variables"

Comment: Having `[POID] = & MfrOrderID &` inside the query string makes no sense. Where is MfrOrderID supposed to come from?

Comment: Also, should use JOIN clauses instead of WHERE - WHERE is for filtering - and there is a solo ) in query.